# Check Format of a string

Tags: c#, string, pattern-matching

What is the smallest amount of C# possible to Check that a String fits this format `#-#####` (1 number, a dash then 5 more numbers).

It seems to me that a regular expression could do this quick (again, I wish I knew regular expressions).

So, here is an example:

```
public bool VerifyBoxNumber (string boxNumber)
{
   // psudo code
   if (boxNumber.FormatMatch("#-#####")
      return true;
   return false;
}
```

If you know real code that will make the above comparison work, please add an answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
private static readonly Regex boxNumberRegex = new Regex(@"^\d-\d{5}$");

public static bool VerifyBoxNumber (string boxNumber)
{
   return boxNumberRegex.IsMatch(boxNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
return Regex.IsMatch(boxNumber, @"^\d-\d{5}$");
```

Answer (score 5):

`^\d-\d{5}$` would be a regexp that matches only this pattern.

Comment: Wow, 3 identical regexps within 32 seconds!

Comment: Think how bad it would be if there were 3 completely different regexps.